# android-ngn-stack registration issue

Tags: android, sip, imsdroid

I am not able to register for `android` with `android-ngn-stack lib`.

Below is my code for registration.

```
 NgnEngine mEngine = NgnEngine.getInstance();
    INgnConfigurationService mConfigurationService
            = mEngine.getConfigurationService();
    mConfigurationService.putString(NgnConfigurationEntry.IDENTITY_IMPI,
            "abcdes"); //username
    mConfigurationService.putString(NgnConfigurationEntry.IDENTITY_IMPU,
            String.format("sip:%s@%s", "sip_username", "sip_domain"));
    mConfigurationService.putString(NgnConfigurationEntry.IDENTITY_PASSWORD,
            "abcdes_abcds");//password
    mConfigurationService.putString(NgnConfigurationEntry.NETWORK_PCSCF_HOST,
            "www.abc.com"); 
    mConfigurationService.putInt(NgnConfigurationEntry.NETWORK_PCSCF_PORT,
            5060);//port
    mConfigurationService.putString(NgnConfigurationEntry.NETWORK_REALM,
            "www.abc.com"); //domain
```

// By default, using 3G for calls disabled

```
    mConfigurationService.putBoolean(NgnConfigurationEntry.NETWORK_USE_3G,
            true);
```

// You may want to leave the registration timeout to the default 1700 seconds

```
    mConfigurationService.putInt(NgnConfigurationEntry.NETWORK_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT,
            3600);
    mConfigurationService.commit();

    // Register broadcast receivers
    initializeManager();
```

Below is the error I am getting.

> 12-26 11:30:19.846 29476-29476/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnNetworkService: netType=0 and netSubType=13
>   12-26 11:30:19.850 29476-30485/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService: Stack started
>   12-26 11:30:19.851 29476-30485/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling E/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService: sessionId to be passed is1
>   12-26 11:30:19.851 29476-30485/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling E/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService: OnDialogEvent (Dialog connecting,1)
>   12-26 11:30:19.851 29476-30485/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling E/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService: --connecting--900
>   12-26 11:30:19.855 29476-30485/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling E/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService: sessionId to be passed is1
>   12-26 11:30:19.855 29476-30485/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling E/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService: OnDialogEvent ((un)REGISTER request successfully sent.,1)
>   12-26 11:30:19.869 29476-29476/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling E/DEBUG: Trying to register...
>   12-26 11:30:19.974 29476-30485/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling E/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService: sessionId to be passed is1
>   12-26 11:30:19.975 29476-30485/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling E/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService: OnDialogEvent (Not found,1)
>   12-26 11:30:19.975 29476-30485/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling E/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService: terminated903
>   12-26 11:30:19.976 29476-29476/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling E/DEBUG: You are now unregistered :)
>   12-26 11:30:19.977 29476-30485/drawer.spicedigital.com.sipcalling D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService: Stack stopped

I have also tried imsdroid apk but that is also not able to get register.
Please help me with some clue where I am doing wrong. As  have followed the same steps.